# Interpretation of interaction b/w two dummy variables and purpose of it

Tags: interaction

Suppose we have the model:

> Y = a + bX + cZ

where X and Z both are dummy variables, and a, b & c are coefficients. What might be the purpose of adding an interaction term between both dummy variables (shown below)? Do you add it if you suspect or know that the dummy variables X and Z are correlated?

What is the interpretation of the interaction term if, let's say, d>0?

> Y = a + bX + cZ + dXZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that the average drop in `glucose` levels in blood when the patient takes `vitamin Z` is `10` mg/dL, so that when the random variable $I_\text{vitZ}=1$, the overall intercept drops 10 units. Now if you give that overly-advertised drug `MegaFarmaXXX` to patients, the drop with respect to the intercept if the indicator variable $I_\text{XXX}=1$ is a whooping `30` units. The amazing thing, though is that if both are present, where $I_\text{interaction}=I_\text{vitZ}\times I_\text{XXX}=1$, the drop is not 40 units, but rather 60 units because of the interaction between the vitamin supplement and the drug from the pharmacy- the interaction brings the intercept down `20` units.

If just one of the variables is continuous, there will be, instead a possible change in the estimated slope. The mathematical expression is:

$Y=\hat \beta_0+\hat \beta_1\,X_1+\hat\beta_2X_2+\hat \beta_3X_1\times X_2+\varepsilon$

So if we take my favorite dataset mtcars{datasets} in R, and we carry out the following regression:

```
(fit <- lm(mpg ~ wt * am, mtcars))

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt * am, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           wt           am        wt:am  
     31.416       -3.786       14.878       -5.298
```

`am`, which dummy-codes for the type of transmission in the car `am` Transmission (`0 = automatic`, `1 = manual`) will give us an intercept of `31.416` for manual (0), and `31.416 + 14.878 = 46.294` for automatic (1). The slope for weight is `-3.786`. And for the interaction, when `am` is 1 (automatic), the regression expression will have the added term, `−5.298 ∗ 1 ∗ weight`, which will add to `−3.786 ∗ weight`, resulting in a slope of `−9.084∗weight`. So we are changing the slope with the interaction.

But let me use the same dataset to actually illustrate your initial question about two categorical variables. Let's look at the effect on miles-per-gallon of automatic engines (as opposed to manual) - the variable `am` as above - and the effect of the a "V" shaped engine in the car (as opposed to a straight engine) - the variable `vs`, first without interaction:

```
> fit=lm(mpg ~ as.factor(am) + as.factor(vs), mtcars)
> fit

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ as.factor(am) + as.factor(vs), data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
   (Intercept)  as.factor(am)1  as.factor(vs)1  
        14.594           6.067           6.929
```

Clearly, there is less gas consumption the fancier you get: you pay less at the pump with automatic transmission, and you pay even less if instead you splurge in a nice "V"-shaped engine.

But what if you get an automatic car with a "V"-shaped engine:

```
> fit2=lm(mpg ~ as.factor(am) *  as.factor(vs), mtcars)
> fit2

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ as.factor(am) * as.factor(vs), data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
                  (Intercept)                 as.factor(am)1  
                       15.050                          4.700  
               as.factor(vs)1  as.factor(am)1:as.factor(vs)1  
                        5.693                          2.929
```

Now you can see that what actually happens is that part of the variability in the gas consumptions is "absorbed" be the interaction of enjoying both luxuries, which brings the `mpg` up. Notice that the initial explanation was oversimplified: in reality, the coefficients for the isolated variables change when the interaction is included, because that part of the variability that was included in the isolated variables is now included in the interaction term.